# How to add page break inside the DETAILS section of SSRS 2008R2 report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

I am a newbie in SSRS.   I want to create a report using SSRS 2008R2.  Please help me.
I have sql stored-procedure ready and pulls the data from the sql server database as shown in the sample below:
I need to divide this data on SSRS report by pulling all records from the dataset  based on the category divide them by putting a page break in the DETAILS section of the report as shown in the image snapshot below:

The sample dataset from the stored-procedure:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6
a        b       c       x      y       z
a1       b1      c1      x1     y1      z1
a2       b2      c2      x2     y2      z2
…        …       …       …      …       …
…        …       …       …      …       …
```

My SSRS 2008 R2 report should be able to show the records based on the category as shown below:
We have only two categories **'A'** or **'B'**.
Each category will be start from new page(i.e. page break)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a group based on Category and select to page break after the group.

To add a group, select the tablix, right-click on the left-most section handles (they look like grey buttons) and select Add Group.